# Plot3D in Mathematica: how to plot in presence of parameters

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I realize I the earlier question was ill-posed. To clarify:

I am trying to find the values of $A$ and $B$ that will maximize a function f on the domain `{x,0,100},{y,0,100}`. I have had trouble using `Maximize` or `NMaximize`, etc.
So I am trying to find `x` and `y` in terms of `A` and `B`, which will maximize a function `f`. The function f is dependent on two parameters: $A$ and $B$, with constraints such that $ 0< A < 100 $ and $A < B \le 100$. The explicit form of the function is:

```
f = (B^3 - B^2 (x + y) + x (A^2 - y^2 + A (-x + y)) + B (x^2 + x y + y^2 - A (x + y)))/(A - B)^2
```

or, for readability,

$$
f=\frac{B^3 - B^2 (x + y) + x (A^2 - y^2 + A (-x + y)) + 
 B (x^2 + x y + y^2 - A (x + y))} {(A - B)^2} $$

Comment: Your original question is very valid. I suggest keeping it, so you do not discourage people answering your question and they do not need to re-edit their answers. You can ask about your optimization problem as a separate question. Also can you post your functions using Mathematica syntax too so it is easy to copy?

Answer (score 9):

Use `Manipulate` function to interactively change the parameters values. The `If` statement is to auto-remove breaking of controls due to getting out of proper range.

```
Manipulate[
 If[B < A, B = A];
 Plot3D[A^3 - A^2 (x + y) + x (B^2 - y^2 + B (-x + y)), {x, 0, 
   100}, {y, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], {{A, 50}, 0, 99.9, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{B, 100}, A, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: @Vitaly:  I see your point , you are right. My second day here :)

Answer (score 5):

Besides interactive manipulation, you might also just want to see a set of surfaces with different parameter settings in a single picture:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@Table[Tooltip[A^3-A^2 (x+y)+x(B^2-y^2+B(-x+y)),
                              Style["A = " <> ToString[A]
                                    <> ", B = "<>ToString[B],
                                    Background->White]],
                      {A, 1, 100, 33}, {B, A, 100, 33}],
       {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100},
       PlotStyle -> {Green, Darker[Yellow], Red, Blue, Cyan, Magenta,
                     Brown, Orange, Purple, Pink}]
```

[image: output of above command]

Comment: To improve visual representation of this vertical `AspectRatio` should be greater and `Opacity` could be helpful.

Comment: @celtschk  Thank you, this is helpful and

Answer (score 2):

Parameters should have numerical values. Otherwise it is done by a standard command `Plot3D`:

```
A = 10; B = 20;
Plot3D[(A^3 - A^2 (x + y) + x (B^2 - y^2 + B (-x + y))), {x, -100, 
  100}, {y, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

If the question is about how to change parameters interactively and see that happens it can be done with `Manipulate`.

Comment: `With[]` is a particularly convenient function for this.